# Expected Date got Number in case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following (slightly insane) piece of code as part of a report (produces a load of metadata).

The problem is that this one snippet throws an ORA-00932 error (expected date got number) for any value of `:i_schedfreq`, despite all cases returning a number.

This happens in both 11g and 12c

```
select case 
      when :i_schedfreq = 'M'  then 
          abs(months_between(trunc(:DateFrom, 'MM'), trunc(:DateTo,'MM')))
      when :i_schedfreq = 'W' then 
          ceil(ceil(trunc(:DateTo) - trunc(:DateFrom) )/7)
      when :i_schedfreq = 'H' then 
          floor((:DateTo - :DateFrom)*24)
      else 
          trunc(:DateTo)- trunc(:DateFrom)
      end as v_diff
from dual
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure that :DateFrom and :DateTo are dates and not some other type representing date?

Comment: Works for me with `:DateFrom` and `:DateTo` as dates, but gives your exact `ORA-00932` error if I make them strings as in @GoranStefanović's comment.

Comment: @GoranStefanović I'm passing dates through from SSRS, and when I run this in OSQLD using date values as per the NLS format I still get the error

Comment: Not all date functions accept strings without a bit of help. For example, my `nls_date_format` is `'DD-MON-RRRR'` but that doesn't mean I can `select months_between(sysdate,trunc('01-JAN-2017','MM')) from dual`.

Comment: Replace all occurences of `:DateFrom` with `to_date(:DateFrom,'DD-MON-YYYY')` (you may need to adjust the date format according to your string parameter). The same for `:DateTo`

Comment: **got number** states you haven't got a string or a date, just a number. **expected date** states what is needed. not much else to say.

Answer (score 0):

So after a day of smashing my head against my desk, I looked at some old reports and found a solution that works.

I have cast the parameters as dates:

```
select case 
         when :i_schedfreq = 'M' 
           then abs(months_between(trunc(cast(:DateFrom as date), 'MM'), trunc(cast(:DateTo as date),'MM')))
         when :i_schedfreq = 'W'
           then ceil(ceil(trunc(cast(:DateTo as date)) - trunc(cast(:DateFrom as date)) )/7)
         when :i_schedfreq = 'H'
           then floor((cast(:DateTo as date) - cast(:DateFrom as date))*24)
         else trunc(cast(:DateTo as date))- trunc(cast(:DateFrom as date))
       end as v_diff
from dual
```